# python3.8 use async getting invalid sysntax

Tags: python-3.8

I am running my script with python3.8 and i have no idea why async is an invalid syntax

```
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I search through the web and most of the solutions are for python3.7 and below, anyone could help?
Appreciate a lot.

Comment: What is the line above look like?

Comment: @Austin do you means one line above? it is `return some_args`

Comment: This script is able to run on other machine, so I highly doubt that i'm missing some of the dependencies.

Comment: I saw twice this problem when upgrading Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20 via do-release-upgrade. The solution was to edit by hand the file /usr/share/pyzo/pyzo/yoton/clientserver.py and change the name of the parameter async on line 81 to assync, as well as two or three lines below. Then I run 'apt --fix-broken install' and the upgrade completed.

Answer (score 0):

async is not a parameter but keyword in python3+, you will have to upgrade the pexpect module if you are running python3 or above and might also need to upgrade the pip.

```
python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3.7 -m pip install pexpect --upgrade
```

and this will work.